# Adding a favicon to a Flask server without HTML

Tags: python, flask, favicon

My flask server constantly reports

```
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

In the code for my flask server I've added,

```
@app.route('/favicon.ico')
def favicon():
    return send_from_directory(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static'),'favicon.ico', mimetype='image/vnd.microsoft.icon')
```

and I've added a favicon titled `favicon.ico` to the same directory that my flask server is running from.

[Favicon location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjaAE.png)

If I try to navigate to `http://www.myurl.com/favicon.ico` I get a 404. My flask server isn't serving an html landing page so I can't add `<link rel='shortcut icon' href='favicon.ico' type='image/x-icon'/ >`  anywhere. I don't really care about actually having a favicon, I just want to stop the error from showing up. How can I serve a favicon/stop the error?

Comment: You said you placed the file in your application's root folder, but your endpoint tries to load it from `static`.

Comment: I added the files to a `static` folder and it worked, thank you!

Answer (score 49):

Put the icon in your **static directory** as favicon.ico. and below code in python file

```
import os
from flask import send_from_directory

@app.route('/favicon.ico')
def favicon():
    return send_from_directory(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static'),
                          'favicon.ico',mimetype='image/vnd.microsoft.icon')
```

href - **http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/favicon/**

Comment: Cheers, simple and easy.

Comment: Yuck! This is what the offical docs' "patterns" section currently recommends, but it's unnecessarily verbose. That entire `send_from_directory(...)` incantation can be replaced with simply `app.send_static_file('favicon.ico')`. There's no need to manually construct the path or specify the mimetype; Flask can do both of those things for your (inferring the mimetype from the `.ico` extension).

Comment: @MarkAmery or `current_app.send_static_file("favicon.ico")` if it is inside a Blueprint

Answer (score 7):

For what it is worth, This worked for me:

```py
from flask import url_for

# Load Browser Favorite Icon
@app.route('/favicon.ico')
def favicon():
    return url_for('static', filename='image/favicon.ico')
```

.

I have my images in the `image` folder inside of the `static` folder.

```
-- app
  -- static
    -- image
      -- favicon.ico
```

```
PS: This was on 
MacOS 12.6 (21G115)
Python 3.10.8
Flask 2.2.2
Jinja2 3.1.2
Viewing in Brave Browser v1.45.116 (Oct 28th, 2022)
```