# How to get rid of favicon.ico in flask restful api?

Tags: rest, flask

I have a simple restful service that has something strange. The code is below:

```
from flask import Flask, make_response
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, fields
from get_response_demo import generate_rest_str
import dia_logging

logger = dia_logging.my_logger("api_rest", "demo.log")

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

resource_fields = {
    'messages': fields.String,
    'jsons': fields.String,
}

class RestAPI(Resource):
    def get(self, sentence):

        dia_result = generate_rest_str(sentence)
        logger.info(dia_result)

        response = make_response(str(dia_result))
        response.mimetype = 'application/json'
        return response

api.add_resource(RestAPI, '/<string:sentence>')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=False, use_reloader=False, host='127.0.0.1', port=4000)
```

And the way I make a request to the service:
http://127.0.0.1:4000/sentence=hello

The restful service is hosted on a Ubuntu machine. On my Mac I didn't observed the problem. And the problem is that, whenever I tested a request to the service, in addition to process the real input sent by the parameter 'sentence', and each time it also processes:

```
INFO:get_response_demo:restful, sentence:favicon.ico
```

So it processes twice for only one request, and the 'favicon.ico' was processed repeatedly.

How to avoid this? I am new to flask.

Answer (score 2):

You have at least three options

1. Add a specific `@app.route('/favicon.ico')` before the `api.add_resource()`
2. If you're running your API behind nginx or Apache, special-case `favicon.ico` in the web server config, so that your Flask code never sees the request
3. Arrange to serve API calls from `/api/...`

The latter future-proofs you if you want to add some admin/monitoring capabilities via root-level URLs. You can use #2 and #3 together.

Comment: when I added @app.route('/favicon.ico') to api.add_resource(), there is an error message popup. saying "@a or def expected". Is that because add_resource is not defined as a function with def?

Comment: I meant, without saying so directly, that you'd also need to add some code. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48386934/62288

Comment: Dave, I don't have an icon picture. Does this hurt if I don't take action? The reason I am asking is that, I set up a simple restful service to process requests. The speed is normal in the beginning, but quickly slow down. I am trying to figure out what's possible cause. I noticed this thing in the log, and suspect it might be the cause. I am new to flask.

Comment: It's normal for a browser to request a favicon and get a 404, so there's no issue from the browser side. From the Flask side, as long as the request doesn't cause something undesirable to happen with the API, it's a question of whether the 404s in the logs bother you. If they don't, ignore them.

Comment: #3 did the job. I have changed my end-point from /foo to /api/foo and the annoying favicon request disappeared.

Comment: @DaveW.Smith re: 3, is the /api/ path something that browsers have standardized on to recognize it as a service?

Comment: @pspahn It's a convention. AFAIK, browsers themselves don't give /api/ special treatment.