# adding a favicon to flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, favicon

I'm trying to follow the instructions given here: [Adding a favicon to a Flask server without HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40696745) on how to add a favicon to a flask app, however its not working for me. Here is my application file:

```
from flask import Flask,send_from_directory
application=Flask(__name__)

@application.route('/')
def main():
    return '<html><p>hello world</p></html>'

@application.route('/favicon.ico')
def favicon():
    return send_from_directory(os.path.join(application.root_path, 'static'),
        'favicon.ico',mimetype='image/vnd.microsoft.icon')

if __name__=='__main__': application.run(debug = True)
```

and here is my directory structure:

```
➜  demo ls -R
application.py static

./static:
favicon.ico
```

When I run the application in Firefox, no favicon is shown, and when I run it in Chrome, the default favicon is shown. I used this website to convert a png into an ico file:
https://www.freeconvert.com/png-to-ico

Please let me know where I'm going wrong.

When I run the app in chrome, I get this error in the console:

```
GET http://localhost:5000/favicon.ico 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)
```

Comment: I copied the same code and my favicon was able to show up in the browser. Have you tried hard reloading/make sure your favicon is valid?

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: `ctrl + shift + R` in ubuntu and `ctrl + F5` on windows will hard reload your browser

Comment: @Mathew If hard reload (as GitauHarrison specified) doesn't work, here's another approach to debug - right click -- inspect, select console. Did you see any errors there?

Comment: @Parzival, I just updated the question so you can see the error message I'm getting.

Comment: @Mathew It does appear that your code is correct, but you're still getting the error. Can you visit this URL: http://localhost:5000/favicon.ico and see what's being returned?

Comment: @Parzival, I just tried that and it took me to a list of errors. I just realized the problem is I'm not importing the os library. The problem is fixed now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks for your message. I’m glad you solved your problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to import `os`, here is the working application:

```
from flask import Flask,send_from_directory
import os
application=Flask(__name__)

@application.route('/')
def main():
    return '<html><p>hello world</p></html>'

@application.route('/favicon.ico')
def favicon():
    return send_from_directory(os.path.join(application.root_path, 'static'),
        'favicon.ico',mimetype='image/vnd.microsoft.icon')

if __name__=='__main__': application.run(debug = True)
```